# Filter directory listing with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

If I have a BASH variable:

```
Exclude="somefile.txt anotherfile.txt"
```

How can I get the contents of a directory but exclude the above to files in the listing? I want to be able to do something like:

```
Files=  #some command here
someprogram ${Files}
```

`someprogram` should be given all of the files in a particular directory, except for those in the `${Exclude}` variable. Modifying `someprogram` is not an option.

Comment: I could envision multiple easy and portable solutions with `sed`, `find` or `grep`, but not sure whether it's worth to figure them out anymore ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you were taking about unix shell scripting, but here's
a working example for bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

Exclude=("a" "b" "c")
Listing=(`ls -1Q`)

Files=( $(comm -23 <( printf "%s\n" "${Listing[@]}" ) <( printf "%s\n" "${Exclude[@]}"
) ) )

echo ${Files[@]}
```

Note that I enclosed every filename in Exclude with double quotes and added
parenthesis around them. Replace `echo` with `someprogram`, change the ls command
to the directory you'd like examined and you should have it working.
The `comm` program is the key, here.

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution because it does not require a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find.  something like:

```
FILES=`find /tmp/my_directory -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -not -name somefile.txt -not -name anotherfile.txt`
```

where /tmp/my_directory is the path you want to search.

You could build up the "-not -name blah -not -name blah2" list from Excludes if you want with a simple for loop...

Comment: Is find portable across major unix-like platforms? BSD, Linux, etc.

Comment: depends on the used flags, but the ones in that command seem to be standard

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner for a standard Unix command line:

ls | grep -v "^${Exclude}$" | xargs

It does have one assumption.  ${Exclude} needs to be properly escaped so charaters like period aren't interpreted as part of the regex.

Comment: That would work if I only had one file I wanted to exclude, but I could have up to 10 (but I don't want to place any arbitrary limit on excluded files).

Comment: @dreamlax Nope: `PATTERNS is one or more patterns separated by newline characters`
You can give multiple patterns ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming filenames with no spaces or other pathological characters:

```
shopt -s extglob
Files=(!(@(${Exclude// /|})))
```